# Image overflow in container

Tags: flutter

I am working on a Flutter app. There is a widget where I need to resize an image to fit in the container.

Here you have the code:

```
Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
                child: Column(

                  children: [

                    Container(

                        child: Image.asset("./assets/slide3.png",)),

                  ],
                ),
              ),

            ),
```

And here you have the output:

[image]

How can I get the image fit the container size and avoid the bottom overflowed by 117 pixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is should be a comment but ok

you need to wrap `Container` with `Expanded`

```
Expanded(
  flex: 2,
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(child: Image.asset("./assets/slide3.png")),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use fit like this

```
Container(height: 200.0,child: Image.asset("./assets/slide3.png",fit: BoxFit.cover,)),
```

Comment: thank you, but why do you decided to put a container height of 200.0, just to test?

Comment: because it is inside Column so either make it flexible using Expanded or specify height like I did which makes the UI consistent as well.